# looping out a sub tree menu over writing current dir paths and placing subs

Tags: php, file, menu, directory

I would like to loop out a subtree menu but I can't figure out how to do this.

I need to overwrite current directory paths and placing subs.

Here is my expected output:

../uploads/username/folder0/|**file1, file2, file3, file4**|

../uploads/username/|**file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7**|folder1/|**file1, file2, file3, file4**|folder2/folder3/|**file1, file2**|folder4/|**file1, file2, file3, file4**|

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$list_array = Array(
    // Presumed to have been coming from a SQL SELECT, populated for demo.
    Array(
        'path' => '../uploads/username/folder0/',
        'subs' => 'file1, file2, file3, file4'
    ),
    Array(
        'path' => '../uploads/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/',
        'subs' => 'file1, file2'
    ),
    Array(
        'path' => '../uploads/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/',
        'subs' => 'file1, file2, file3'
    ),
    Array(
        'path' => '../uploads/username/',
        'subs' => 'file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6 file7'
    ),
    Array(
        'path' => '../uploads/username/folder1/',
        'subs' => 'file1, file2, file3, file4'
    )
);

$x = 1;

foreach ($list_array as $list_arrays) {
    //do something with loop        
}

?>
```

Comment: This question seems to be mis-tagged wrt 'sql':

Comment: @collapsar You can edit the question and update tags